# Генерация массива со временем с интервалом в 30 минут

Tags: php

Как с помощью php получить список со временем с интервалом в полчаса?

В бд у меня есть строка с интервалом, например, "10:00-18:00". Необходимо разбить этот интервал на маленькие кусочки, чтобы на выходе получился массив такого типа:

[['time' => '10:00'],['time' => '10:30'], ... , ['time' => '18:00']]

Comment: Интервал то всегда на 00 заканчивается?

Comment: Интервал может идти как от 30 минут так и от 00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$timeline = explode('-', '10:00-18:00');

function hoursRange($lower = 0, $upper = 86400, $step = 3600)
{
    $times = [];

    foreach (range($lower, $upper, $step) as $increment)
    {
        $increment = gmdate('H:i', $increment);
        list($hour, $minutes) = explode(':', $increment);

        $date = new DateTime($hour.':'.$minutes);

        $times[]['time'] = (string) $increment;
    }

    return $times;
}

function timeToSec($time, $sec = 0)
{
    foreach (array_reverse(explode(':', $time.':00')) as $k => $v)
        $sec += pow(60, $k) * $v;

    return $sec;
}

$range = hoursRange(timeToSec($timeline[0]), timeToSec($timeline[1]), 60 * 30);

print_r($range);
```

Также можно рассмотреть еще один вариант с уже описанной выше функцией `timeToSec`:

```
$timeline = explode('-', '10:00-18:00');

function hoursRange2($lower = 0, $upper = 86400, $step = 3600)
{
    return array_map(function($time) {
        return ['time' => gmdate('H:i', $time)];
    }, range($lower, $upper, $step));
}

function timeToSec($time, $sec = 0)
{
    foreach (array_reverse(explode(':', $time.':00')) as $k => $v)
        $sec += pow(60, $k) * $v;

    return $sec;
}

$range = hoursRange2(timeToSec($timeline[0]), timeToSec($timeline[1]), 60 * 30);

print_r($range);
```

Comment: Спасибо, ваш код помог решить поставленную задачу!

Answer (score 0):

```
$interval = '10:00-18:15';
$interval = explode('-', $interval);

$firstDate = explode(':', $interval[0]);
$firstDate = (new DateTime())->setTime($firstDate[0], $firstDate[1]);

$secondDate = explode(':', $interval[1]);
$secondDate = (new DateTime())->setTime($secondDate[0], $secondDate[1]);

//  Можно так инициализировать $firstDate и $secondDate
// $var = array('firstDate', 'secondDate');
// foreach ($var as $key => $value) {
//  ${$value} = explode(':', $interval[$key]);
//  $firstDate = (new DateTime())->setTime(${$value}[0], ${$value}[1]);
// }

$result = [];
while ($firstDate < $secondDate) {
    $result[] = ['time' => $firstDate->format('H:i')];
    $firstDate->modify("+30 minutes");
}
$result[] = ['time' => $secondDate->format('H:i')];

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: У вас в конце добавляется еще 15 минут, проверьте

Comment: @Let'ssayPie я на примере взял `10:00-18:15` (первая строчка), чтобы сразу показать что будет в таких ситуациях. Логично что при `10:00-18:00` - все будет тип-топ.

Comment: не заметил что-то, сорри :)

Comment: Спасибо, код рабочий и делает все ровно так, как нужно!